# Android NDK how to create Image from Image Array

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an `JintArray` in `JNI`. From that i want to create an image file .

Right now I am creating an image by passing that array to java side and then making that array to image. But it looks slow while using continuously .

To create more no of images i want to do that process in `JNI` itself.

```
 jintArray ret = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, pixels);
    (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, ret, 0, pixels, (jint *)pixbuf);
    free(pixbuf);
    LogD("NBridge: Returning data.");
    return ret;
```

This is what i am doing at last . ret is the image array which i am having.

**Edit** 
Java code to convert int[] to image

**pixels is the int[] which i am getting from jni .**

```
 Bitmap bmp_ss = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap_width,
                bitmap_height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bmp_ss.setPixels(pixels, 0, screen_width,
                0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
 Matrix rotator = new Matrix();
            switch (rotation) {
            case (Surface.ROTATION_0):
                break;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_90):
                rotator.postRotate(0);
                break;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_180):
                rotator.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case (Surface.ROTATION_270):
                rotator.postRotate(0);
                break;


    bmp_ss = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp_ss, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height, rotator, false);
try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException();
            }
            bmp_ss.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, fos);
```

Comment: Show us your current source code!

Comment: hi sergey. i  have added the code in edit .

Comment: You're allocating a new int[] every time.  Can you allocate a buffer once and re-use it?

Comment: hi fadden how to do it ??? and also i am getting int[] everytime because everytime i am getting the new image data. could you advice me how to use buffer there ?

Comment: What kind of image file are you creating in Java? Please post the relevant fragment of Java code that takes int[] and produces the file.

Comment: hi alex cohn i have added the code in edit .

Comment: @Rajesh: your Java code rotates the ARGB bitmap and compresses it into JPEG buffer. The latter operation takes most of the time, I believe. If you want to speed the process up, consider if you can start with YUV buffer instead of RGB.